# when using WEBRTC to stream video between peers, ontrack function is never called

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am doing a video chat, and in the first steps i am trying to deeply understand WEBRTC. I'm not to the signalling part yet, so I am doing it 'by hand' as shown here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FExZvpVvYxA&t=3626s&ab_channel=HusseinNasser ,Then i get a stream from the navigator and create an offer which I manually paste in the other peer. Then I create an answer and repeat the process the other way around. The add track function seems to work without a problem, but the function ontrack is never called in the other peer.

here is the code I wrote for the 'main' peer, even looping in the streams tracks and adding them one by one doesn't work

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
    { video: true, audio: true }).then(stream => {
        document.getElementById('video').srcObject = stream;
        document.getElementById('video').play()
        localConnection.addTrack(stream.getTracks()[0])
        return localConnection.createOffer();
    }).then(() => {
        offer => applicationCache.setLocalDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(localConnection.localDescription))
    })
```

here the code for the answering peer who should get the video and play it

```
remoteConnection.ontrack = e => {
       document.getElementById('video1').srcObject = e.streams[0];
       document.getElementById('video1').play();
       console.log('i'm triggered');
};
```

thanks for any help :)

Comment: just following the various examples that i've seen for webrtc, when adding track, the second argument should be the stream object, but you don't seem to be using that.

Comment: Well I also followed some tutorial from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/addTrack and i tried both ways. Neither worked :/